# django-cms apphook with relative urls

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Using: django-cms 2.2, python 2.7, django 1.3.1

I have Apphook that I attach to some django-cms page. It has urls:

```
url(r'^(?P<gallery_id>\d+)-?.*$','details', name='gallery_details'),
```

Lets say this page has url `/galleries_foo/` (slug)

When in template I generate url for gallery `{% url gallery_details gallery.id %}` I get url `/galleries/1`. Whan I want to get is `/galleries_foo/1/`. What am I doing wrong and is it even possible with django-cms?

Answer (score 0):

You should make 'foo' an url argument. For example:

```
url(r'^(?P<gallery_id>\d+)-?(?P<slug>.*)$','details', name='gallery_details'),
```

Will enable:

```
{% url gallery_details gallery.id gallery.slug %}
```

That said, you don't need the id at all if the slug is unique.

Comment: Yeah but problem is not here. As I understand it doesn't reload urls after creating page and doesn't create urls. If I restart server it's OK.

Comment: What do you mean "creating a page" ? The server should reload when the Python code changes, that's for sure.

Comment: When I create django-cms page + attach apphook to it attaches menu urls to that page url. Problem is that it doesn't work unless I restart django app. I have found it here: http://code.michaelrog.com/franckbret/cmsplugin-photologue/overview : - add plugins to pages, or attach 'Photologue plugin app' and 'Photologue plugin navigation' to a page (you may have to restart server process for urls to an attached page to work, something with how django-cms caches urls)

Comment: I hope django-cms does no such thing as url caching. The urls are loaded in python when the server starts. When you change urls, you change python, you have to restart the server. That's just the way it is :)